# Placing Panels Content Above Menu

Tags: routes, blocks, nodes, panels, theming

I am trying to use panels to implement something that in the past I had done with blocks. My theme has a region called "content top", this displays content above the secondary menu (the tabbed menu that every node has with view edit etc). When I switch over to panels, I can't figure out how to place content in any other region except for the main area ... any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panels are page nodes and can not be put into regions as we do with blocks. Try mini panels to create panels for regions or itself panels.

Comment: Is there any way to move the menu into the panel then? The menu seems to appear above the panel even when you override blocks and regions

Comment: For every menu there is an associated menu block created by menu module that can be put into any region or panel.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I was referring to MENU_LOCAL_TASK (the tabbed menu) not the primary or secondary.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all standard Drupal blocks in the panel page settings and add menu directly to panel.